# Unit measurement lines in CSS around the shape div

Tags: css, sass

So I want to create something what you can see in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mkungla/pen/rLOMxE/) however as I was getting into point to add arrows into both ends I realized that I have started that all out in a wrong way. My CSS will grow way to long for such small thing and will have probably problem with other elements on the page. I could not figure out what's the best approach to create these left and bottom lines with arrows in both ends and value from attribute so I hope some of you can point me out to right direction.

```css
.ruler-left:after {
    content: attr(data-height);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.ruler-bottom {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    height: 2px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.ruler-bottom:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid Gainsboro;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid Gainsboro;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
}
.ruler-bottom:after {
    content: attr(data-width);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.shape {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: white;
    height: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
     <hr class="ruler-left" data-height="30 mm">
     <div class="shape">Shape image</div>
     <hr class="ruler-bottom" data-width="30 mm">
</div>
```

Comment: CSS arrows usually end up being fairly long code wise, and there aren't many ways to get around it. One solution I've used in the past, is have the arrows as SVG icons (having them in an icon-font or something) and then positioning a span at the end of the line. However someone else might have a more elegant solution that is pure css.

Comment: So using something like font-awesome or glyphicons for arrows could be option?.

Comment: yep, that's definitely something you can do. It comes with it's own inherent problems though - some users may have weird browser/zoom/font settings on their computer which can make it look strange for them, but any font/glyph icon implementation would face the same problems

Comment: a good resource to look at, if you only want the font for the arrows (and perhaps one or two other elements) is to create a custom set using icomoon.io (https://icomoon.io/app)

Answer (score 1):

I played with your problem a little...

[See my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/zp3k6a94/)

I kept most of your CSS, but dropped the `:before` pseudos wich were rendering arrows.
I kept the `:after` pseudos wich show dimentions.

To draw the left and right arrows, I used classes wich only draw a triangle with the `border` of an element.
I applied those two classes on another element (I used `hr` again... Could be something else) placed before and after your «ruler» `hr`.
These three `hr` are wrapped in a `div` for positioning and rotation.

**CSS**

```
.arrowRight{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000;
}
.arrowLeft{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 16px 8px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000000 transparent transparent;
}

/* -------- */
.shape {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: white;
    height: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 230px;
}
.shape-container {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    background: Gainsboro;
    padding: 2px;
}
.ruler-left-div {
    position:absolute;
    left:-104px;
    top:110px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.ruler-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 2px;
}
.ruler-left:after {
    content: attr(data-width);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.ruler-bottom-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:8px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
    height: 20px;
}
.ruler-bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
.ruler-bottom:after {
    content: attr(data-height);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="shape-container">
    <div class="ruler-left-div"><hr class="arrowLeft"><hr class="ruler-left" data-width="30 mm"><hr class="arrowRight"></div>
    <div class="shape">
      shape image
    </div>
    <div class="ruler-bottom-div"><hr class="arrowLeft"><hr class="ruler-bottom"  data-height="30 mm"><hr class="arrowRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time for this, as I see CSS grows fairly long so I'm thinking would some svg or iconic font be more proper way to go for this.
Let's assume that iconic font is loaded anyway.

Comment: I tryed with an SVG image fast made on [drawsvg.org](http://www.drawsvg.org/). It works, but I'm not sur it's easier this way! Had fun trying anyway. See [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/hyjqcqn4/). Good luck! I'll check for future answers to your question. ;)